# All solutions to functional equation $f(x+1)-f(x)=1$

Tags: functional-equations, periodic-functions

I was thinking of the possibility of finding all solutions other than $f(x)=x$ for the functional equation:

$f(x+1)-f(x)=1$

If there are other solutions, what will be some restrictions for the equation to have just one solution?

Comment: For a solution $f$, what can you say about $g(x) = f(x)-x$?

Comment: Well, It follows that $g(x+1)=g(x)$, so $g$ can be any function with periodicity of $1$?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Do you want continuous functions?  If not necessarily, floor funtion satisfies

Comment: Yes, I want continuous functions. Second part of the question is important for me. Is there a condition for the equation such that the $f(x)=x$ is the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, think about all functions $g$ of period 1, we have f$(x+1)$=f$(x)$, we can make one period constant, then let value of function in last period substract 1, and let value of function in following period add 1. Repeat it, and you can get a new function.

Answer (score 0):

For all function g of period 1 the function f(x) = [x] + g(x) works; for example f(x) = [x] + sin 2$\pi$x